# Schema - Star rating vanished from Google: “The review does not have a reviewed item with a name specified”

Tags: json, schema

My visual star rating for my webpage has vanished (it used to show until recently) when my page shows up in the Google search results. It used to show along with the page.

I ran the structured data testing tool and got this result:

"The review does not have a reviewed item with a name specified."

AggregateRating1 ERROR0 WARNINGSexpand_less @type

AggregateRating ratingValue

5 reviewCount

4 itemReviewed

@type

Product cancel

"The review does not have a reviewed item with a name specified".

Here is the code:

Any idea what's wrong or can anyone edit the code correctly? I am a layman at coding and using guesswork at best.

5 stars - based on 4 reviews

Comment: Code:

</script>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span> stars - based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">4</span> reviews
    <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <!-- Product properties -->
    </div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

To get it fixed I had to add this to my H1 tag:

`<h1 itemprop="name">Text</h1>`

*** The Complete Code ***

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="item name" />
<meta itemprop="description" content="item description." />
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="date added" />
<meta itemprop="url" content="url" />
<meta itemprop="image" content="thumb" />

<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
 <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
 <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1" />
 <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="rank" />
 <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="rates" />
</div>
```

***You can see it works with the example above:***
[Google Structured Data Success](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.girlsugames.com%2Fgame%2Fprincess-flower-crown)

***And here is a page without the example above***
[Google Structured Data Faild](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hannywbarek.com%2Fsuccess-greetings%2Fpreview%2F665)

Hope it can help you.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Tried a number of variations but still get the same error. Thank you for trying anyway, I appreciate it!

Comment: Hi, I am sorry to hear it didn't work for you, but I have updated my answer to see the complete code and how it successfully works and the error has been removed.

Comment: Strange! I still got the same JSON-LD error, exactly the same as before.

Also had a new error from the new code: <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">  (itemReviewed
 
A value for the itemReviewed field is required.) which I am sure is an easy fix but strange about the persistent JSON-LD error

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. But it would be better to use aggregate rating under the product schema.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="schema.org/AggregateRating">
<span itemprop="name">item name</span>
<span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span> stars - based on 
<span itemprop="reviewCount">4</span> reviews
<div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="schema.org/Product"> 
<span itemprop="name">item name</span> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that seems to have made some difference, however, now I'm getting "JSON-LD
 
Syntax error: value, object or array expected."

As posted in the image in my other comment

Comment: Apart from the JSON error, the stars are visually appearing in Google search results again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

JSON-LD

Syntax error: value, object or array expected.

```
    <p><script type="application/ld+json"><br />
{<br />
  "@context": "http://schema.org",<br />
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",<br />
  "url": "XXX",<br />
  "image": "XXX.jpg",<br />
  "name": "XXX",<br />
  "telephone": "XXX",<br />
  "priceRange": "Enquire",<br />
"address": {<br />
      "@type": "PostalAddress",<br />
      "streetAddress": "XXX",<br />
      "addressLocality": "XXX",<br />
      "addressRegion": "XXX",<br />
      "postalCode": "XXX"<br />
},<br />
  "contactPoint": {<br />
    "@type": "ContactPoint",<br />
    "telephone": "XXX",<br />
    "contactType": "Customer service",<br />
    "areaServed": ["XXX", "XXX"]<br />
  }<br />
}<br />
</script></p>
<div itemscope="" itemtype="schema.org/AggregateRating">
<span itemprop="name">XXX</span><br />
<span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span> stars &#8211; based on<br />
<span itemprop="reviewCount">4</span> reviews</p>
<div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope="" itemtype="schema.org/Product">
<span itemprop="name">XXX</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The error is specifically on this line:

<p><script type="application/ld+json"><br />

Where the >< is

Answer (score 0):

If anything, up until this point, my original problem of the star reviews vanishing in Google search results has been fixed (now appearing in Google search results!) but still getting the "JSON-LD Syntax error: value, object or array expected." from the analyser.